# Resolve-Path returns null in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have the command

```
$logFile = Resolve-Path "Db_Upgrade.log"
```

But in the PowerGUI Script Editor `$logFile` is `null` after running this line in my script.  Any idea why `Resolve-Path` would be failing to give me a path for my log file?

Comment: Does the file exist and is it in the working directory that the script is executing in?

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up manually figuring out what the path of a new file in the working directory would be

```
#Get the current working directory
$PSScriptRoot = Split-Path -Parent -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
#Path to log file is working directory + "DatabaseLog.log"
$logFile = $PSScriptRoot + "\DatabaseLog.log"
```

Comment: FTR: `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition` produces the full path of the script. The folder the script resides in is not necessarily the working directory.

Comment: Or you could just use the automatic variable `$PSScriptRoot` if you're on V3 or higher.